# Adult children?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there one word or a better way to say or refer to one's "adult children"? I have never found quite the right word, and "offspring" doesn't really say it.

> "That couple has two ________: one is a lawyer and the other is a politician."

Comment: *adult children* is the right term. I know of no single word for this.

Comment: _grown children_ (i.e., children who have grown up) is another possibility, but less common.

Comment: @xanne "grown children" is much more common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Adult+children%2Cgrown+children

Comment: I'm partial to *spawn*, or if you want a longer term then *fruits of their loins*.

Comment: I prefer "kids" to children as "children" sounds kinda clinical and less jocular/playful/swaggering/good-cheer/laughing-at-life etc  Adult kids, 'grown kids", "kids are out of the house" (possibly out of the house)

Comment: I prefer "grown children" or "grown kids". "Adult children" has another meaning and context in 12 step and self help lingo. "Adult children" comes from "adult children of alcoholics", but now has broader reference to adults  who were abused emotionally, physically or sexually in childhood.

Comment: @Palizsche yeah, maybe that frequent and conventional use with "surivors" in a clinical setting is what gives "adult children" the wrong flavor for informal or friendly or even (to a degree) positive reference.

Comment: @Spencer "adult children" is more common actually; you Ngrammed (a new verb!) capital A in adult.See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grown+children%2C+adult+children%2C+grown-up+children&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrown%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadult%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrown%20-%20up%20children%3B%2Cc0

Comment: For me, the words son and daughter don't have the assocation with immaturity. "They have two daughters, one is a forester and the other a business student" or "Both their sons are lawyers."

Comment: I think if you say they are a lawyer and a politician most people will get the message that they are adults. (Though my twelve-year-old grandson often comes across as both, often over how much I owe him.) Use 'adult children', nothing wrong with that!

Comment: @Morphyus , You could think about it in this frame of reference: What is the purpose of the word "grandchildren", in the context of "children"? 

"A person has 2 children and 4 grand children."

An adjective is unneeded in in the context. What I believe is lacking and what others are suggesting, is that in your case context is what really key rather than the word usage. 

This just happens to the one of the many blind spots in the English Language.

Answer (score 3):

The word remains "children" regardless of their age. You can elaborate on that with "grown-up children" or, more awkwardly, "adult children" but if you're explaining that somebody's children are a lawyer and a politician then their adulthood is implied.

Child: son or daughter of human parents.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/child

Comment: *Grown-up* does make it sound like you talking *to* children, though. There's also simple *grown*.

Comment: @Ily, I wonder if that's a difference between BrE and AmE? "Grown-up" would, I think, be more common in British English.

Comment: The noun *grown up* is perfectly common in American English. It's just part of the register used to speak to children, like *go potty* and *get a boo boo*. You could say *she's all grown up*, sure, but [*grown children* is more common in every dialect of English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grown+children%2C+grown-up+children%2C+grown+up+children&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) since they're definitionally not children any more.

Comment: That is interesting, though. Wonder what other words negate their surface meanings by adding standard adjectives (i.e., adjectives apart from *no* &c.).

Answer (score 0):

The most common and best way to refer to your adult children is

## children

That's it. The *OED* entry has [16 primary senses](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31619) for child but there's two main ones

> A newborn child, esp. a girl; a young person below the age of puberty, esp. a boy
>
> The offspring of human parents; a son or daughter of any age

This isn't confusing at all. Given that everyone is the child of someone, *He's a child* means that he either is a boy or acts with the petulant selfishness of one. *He's my child* means he is the offspring, issue, get, fruit &c. of my loins in union with someone else's. Adding *adult* just makes it weird and offputting and, if anything, pushes it back into the other definition: you're making him sound childish instead of like your child.

If you just wanted to sound lawyerly, though, the legal jargon is usually **issue** or, where grandchildren & al. are included, **descendant**. You shouldn't talk to or about your own kids that way, though, unless you want them to think you've been talking to an attorney recently and they should be nervous about the contents of your will.

Comment: you're right that in the example he gave, the context the lawyer and politician professions provide make any word like "adult" or "grown" unnecessary.  If, however, you were asking, "Would you like me to introduce you to Sarah? She's an engineer and has two children.... the most common thing to assume is that, without qualification, children would most likely be under 12.  (if they were teens I would use that instead of children) .

Comment: I've heard people who remarry mention that, e.g., "she had two adult children"--

Comment: @Tom22 That might be valid on an anonymous website but in person, for the *vast* majority of cases, it remains perfectly clear how old a woman's children are. Sure, men *could* have kids of all ages and there are exceptions but I don't think there are any contexts where it matters how old the children are where you can't tell from context on your own whether they are old enough to be out of college or not.

Comment: @Xanne You could go ahead and clarify if you like, sure, but it's unnecessary and less common and, when you do, it's much more common to refer to *grown children*, as someone already mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As Drew said in a comment to the question, "adult children" is the right phrase.

Some have suggested "grown children" and "grown-up children", but since the 1970s "adult children" has been the prevalent phrase both [in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adult+children%2Cgrown+children%2Cgrown+-+up+children&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadult%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrown%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrown%20--%20up%20children%3B%2Cc0) and [in American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adult+children%2Cgrown+children%2Cgrown+-+up+children&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadult%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrown%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrown%20--%20up%20children%3B%2Cc0).

Yes, *some* contexts will give additional info from which readers can infer that the children are adults anyway. But not all. It may well be not clear at all "how old a woman's children are", to pick up a comment from lly to their own answer: the writer might know how old the woman is but the reader won't unless the writer has stated that, too. Consider a potted bio of, e.g. a book's author in that book's blurb. And, as lly suggests, this argument doesn't apply to men.

Answer (score 0):

How about Kidults? Ugly but I've heard people use it. I really don't like saying 'my children are coming for the weekend.'

Comment: _Kidults_ would suggest to me kids who act like adults or possibly adults who act like kids rather than simply grown up children.

Comment: You don't like saying "my children are coming for the weekend", but are you saying you actually prefer "my kidults are coming"? I agree with KillingTime that "kidult" suggests an adult acting like a kid.

Answer (score -4):

We need a NEW word that means "adult child". "Adult child" is an oxymoron and that is not something the adult child wants to be. Therefore, let me name the new word. Your adult child shall henceforth be called: "spawn." It is gender neutral and may include other offspring than only adult children.

Comment: Your suggestion in no way supercedes the comments' on the OP's post..